# How to prevent firefox sending my os info to google?

Tags: firefox, google-search, privacy

[automatically added "client=ubuntu"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeU5j.png)
When I google, firefox adds "client=ubuntu" to get request.
How can I stop this?

I had tried to change "general.useragent.override" in about:config, but it seems that it doesn't help. Also, I prefer to find a solution without add-ons (I am aware of user-agenr switcher) or downloading someone's other user.js, but I would appreciate these kind of answers too.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what OS/user agent does [amiunique.org](https://amiunique.org) say you have?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu..., as expected

Comment: stupid idea: see if this overriding method works https://superuser.com/a/1284285

Comment: @11belowstudio no, I don't want to mess with my user agent in general, I only want to remove this request to google